# Bind nested listview from ViewModel in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am beginner in WPF. I am trying bind nested listview from ViewModel.

I have two listview parent and child respectively. In my parent listview datatemplate want bind child listview it's something

like nested gridview in asp.net. Could any one there please help me to sort out this problem.

Data Display like:

StudentID   Name

S101        Azad

Math      3

C#            3

Here StudentID,Name parent listview content and subjects are child listview content which is filter by StudentID.

Thanks,

Az@d

Answer (score 1):

```
    <Grid>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Students}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RollNo}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SubjectAndMarks}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Subject}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Marks}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>

    public class SubjectAndMarks 
{
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public double Marks { get; set; }
}
public class Student 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int RollNo { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<SubjectAndMarks> SubjectAndMarks { get; set; }
}
public class ViewModel //ViewModel
{
     public ObservableCollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Students = new ObservableCollection<Student>();
        Students.Add(new Student()
        {
            Name = "Harish",
            RollNo = 1,
            SubjectAndMarks = new ObservableCollection<SubjectAndMarks>()
        {new SubjectAndMarks(){Subject="Maths",Marks=100},new SubjectAndMarks(){Subject="Hindi",Marks=100},
        new SubjectAndMarks(){Subject="Science",Marks=100}}
        });
        Students.Add(new Student()
        {
            Name = "Pankaj",
            RollNo = 2,
            SubjectAndMarks = new ObservableCollection<SubjectAndMarks>()
        {new SubjectAndMarks(){Subject="Maths",Marks=100},new SubjectAndMarks(){Subject="Hindi",Marks=40},
        new SubjectAndMarks(){Subject="Science",Marks=30}}
        });
        Students.Add(new Student()
        {
            Name = "Deepak",
            RollNo = 3,
            SubjectAndMarks = new ObservableCollection<SubjectAndMarks>()
        {new SubjectAndMarks(){Subject="Maths",Marks=90},new SubjectAndMarks(){Subject="Hindi",Marks=50},
        new SubjectAndMarks(){Subject="Science",Marks=60}}
        });
    } 
}
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();   
    }
```

I hope that will help.

Comment: This is just an example you can keep any you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually I don't like to keep my subject Marks inside Student class rather i would like to read this data every time when new row is created in listview. To do this I took one TextBlock inside listview item template and in textblock initialize event i binded child listview. All the job i did in code behind but can not catch the text block initialized event in view model. any idea about it or any listview event like rowcreated which i will catch from view model.

Comment: That will be worst implementation. Why dont you fetch all data alltogether, Why you want to fetch data one by one item.